# FileNotFoundException - But, file exists. Tried URLEncoder.encode() too

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read some xml files from a folder. I'm able to read 3 out of 5 files. But, 2 xmls throws `FileNotFoundException`.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /pd00/test/myspace/workspace/xml/info.xml  (No such file or directory)
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Even I have hardcoded the path and tried. I'm using SAXParser to parse the xmls where I get this exception.

```
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            saxParser.parse(theXml, saxHandler);
```

The above lines are in a method called inputParsing. Then, i call this from another method beginParse using

```html
int beginParse(String theField){
    Integer.parseInt(inputParsing(theXml, theField).getOffset()) - 1;
```

The above beginParse method is called from another class by creating an instance for the above method's enclosing Class like:

```html
Parsing parser = new Parsing();
parser.beginParse("NAME");
```

What could be the problem.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code: the code before the SAXParser creation.

Comment: @amedeoavogadro : I have added few more lines

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is better if you post the code in which you create the File descriptor. Anyway I suggest you to do a debug step by step, this way you can easily find why you're getting a FileNotFoundException

Comment: @amedeoavogadro: The problem particularly for this instance I have the problem. I'm accessing this class with another instance for some other thing.. where I can access other files without any exception.

Answer (score 1):

I once came across the same problem. But, the thing was very silly that I had given the paths in a config file, in which there was a space appended to the file path.

Just check that. Because, often there may be spaces appended to the end of strings.

Comment: yes. seems there is a space appended to the path name. But, how come the thing was able to get executed in Windows but throws error in linux?